# conda update conda does not update conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I had some problems with anaconda, so I decided to uninstall and reinstall it.
To do that I used anaconda-clean and ran the following command:

`rm -rf ~/opt/anaconda3`

The version that was installed is 4.12.0 and I wanted to update to the most recent, 22.9.0, but whenever I run

`conda update conda`

or

`conda update -n base conda`

and check the version

`conda --version`

I keep getting 4.12.0

Is there a way to solve this or find out if something went wrong when I deleted/installed anaconda?

Thanks!
Lu

Comment: I have been facing the same issue as well for quite some time. My base environment is strictly restricted to having only `conda` (and `mamba`) and nothing more. Everything else gets its own environment. Any chance that you have installed `mamba` too in the same environment?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem due to an old version of Python in `base`. Conda recommends against upgrading python in an environment, but for `base` I am not sure if there is a better option. In the end, the following did the trick (running in `base`):

```
conda install python=3.10 conda=23.5
```

From there you could run `conda update --all` for good measure.

Interestingly, we see a hint of why there might be problems in the run logs:

```
...
The following packages will be UPDATED:

  conda                               4.13.0-py38h06a4308_0 --> 23.5.0-py310h06a4308_0
  python                                  3.8.16-h7a1cb2a_3 --> 3.10.11-h7a1cb2a_2

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  brotlipy                          0.7.0-py38h27cfd23_1003 --> 0.7.0-py310h7f8727e_1002
  certifi                           2023.5.7-py38h06a4308_0 --> 2023.5.7-py310h06a4308_0
  cffi                                1.15.1-py38h5eee18b_3 --> 1.15.1-py310h5eee18b_3
  conda-package-han~                   2.1.0-py38h06a4308_0 --> 1.9.0-py310h5eee18b_1
  cryptography                        39.0.1-py38h9ce1e76_0 --> 39.0.1-py310h9ce1e76_0
  idna                                   3.4-py38h06a4308_0 --> 3.4-py310h06a4308_0
  pip                                 23.0.1-py38h06a4308_0 --> 23.0.1-py310h06a4308_0
  pycosat                              0.6.4-py38h5eee18b_0 --> 0.6.4-py310h5eee18b_0
  pyopenssl                           23.0.0-py38h06a4308_0 --> 23.0.0-py310h06a4308_0
  pysocks                              1.7.1-py38h06a4308_0 --> 1.7.1-py310h06a4308_0
  requests                            2.29.0-py38h06a4308_0 --> 2.29.0-py310h06a4308_0
  setuptools                          67.8.0-py38h06a4308_0 --> 67.8.0-py310h06a4308_0
  urllib3                            1.26.15-py38h06a4308_0 --> 1.26.15-py310h06a4308_0
  wheel                               0.38.4-py38h06a4308_0 --> 0.38.4-py310h06a4308_0
...
```

Might be my misreading, but it seems like the conda versioning order is a bit messed up due to placing `py37xxx`, `py38xxx`, etc. *after* `py310xxx`, `py311xxx`, etc. by alphabetical rather than semantic ordering. So simply running update prefers not to "downgrade" these packages, unless you specifically request it.

Answer (score 4):

Running `conda update conda` will make a best-effort attempt to update your environment. Unfortunately, you may have packages installed that prevents the update.

You can alternatively try a more explicit install:

```
conda install -n base conda=22.9.0
```

If this still fails please open an issue at https://github.com/conda/conda so the conda team can help debug further.

Comment: I can't get conda to update to 23.3.1 (at least not using `conda update -n base -c defaults conda`), but `conda install -n base conda=22.9.0` got be from 4.12.0 to 22.9.0.

Answer (score 4):

You likely have an old version of python in your base env with dependancies preventing automatic python update.

Running `conda update python` may solve this problem.
alternatively, you can install a specific version of python explicitly e.g.,
`conda install python=3.9`

Comment: It is not recommended to install another python version explicity: 

https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing same issue . I updated conda-repo-cli  using `conda install -c anaconda conda-repo-cli`
it automatically updated conda from 4.13.0 to 23.3.1.Hopefully , it may help.
You can check this issue on github [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9469)

Comment: This fix described in the above-mentioned github thread solved my problem: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9469#issuecomment-1503302008

`conda update -n base -c defaults conda --repodata-fn=repodata.json`

Comment: This did not solve the problem. I think the issue is the Python version as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:
`conda update --force conda`

I always get stopped on some dependencies if I don't use `--force`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This did nothing

Answer (score 0):

Removing a bunch of packages from the base environment (the huge number of packages in Anaconda base environment create a dependency conflicts nightmare) worked for me.

Try running the following in your base (root) environment:

**conda remove statsmodels spyder sphinx scipy scikit-learn pytest numba numexpr mkl lxml flask debugpy dask cloudpickle bokeh beautifulsoup4**

Then after everything has been removed successfully, run:
**conda update –all**

And with any luck, conda should be updated to the latest version. This worked in November 2023...so for later dates / versions of Anaconda you may need to remove more packages...